# Ever Increasing Counteroffers

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Why is it that even when I offer a merchant profits of over 3k, he first counteroffers with him getting profit of over 6k after which I lower his profit to 5k and he counteroffers for a profit of over 9k? I ended up having to give him 7k profit because that trade was going to give me a lot of much needed materials. Usually, traders will accept as low as 1k profit; why were these demands suddenly so high? Does it have to do with the fact that I brought a lot of goods to the depot, or is there some other factor I'm missing?

Comment: Was your attending broker skilled in the arts of commerce?

Comment: Level 14 - Grand Master Appraiser. That's also why this a little weird.

Comment: Was the value of goods you wanted to buy significantly greater than what you previously traded for?

Comment: I was buying a looooooot of stuff. I think it was worth around 10k. And on this fortress I hadn't done much previous trading. I have only had a few successful trades before, and they were for way less stuff.

Comment: Appraisal is only one art of commerce, was he a poor negotiator? I think that's the skill responsible for actual bargaining, while appraiser simply gives you better information about the value of goods.

Comment: Ah, he is only a Novice negotiator. That could be part of the problem if you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've experienced this same thing. I believe it is because when you make an offer which is not accepted, it lowers the friendliness of the merchant towards you, causing them to be less willing to accept a lower profit, and to try to demand a higher profit. I usually follow a rule of giving them a profit approximately half as much as the value of the traded goods. Following this rule, I very rarely have problems with them not immediately accepting.

Comment: Ya, that might be it. It was just weird that this happened from the get-go on my first offer (he started out neutral, too). Do you think that bringing too many trade goods to the depot could be the issue? I mean, he can't counter offer if the stuff isn't there to begin with.

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference. If you don't have the goods there, he just says something about you never being able to get what you want if that's all you have to offer. And the reason it happened on your first offer was because you offered him only a 10% profit. As I said, they usually want at least a 50% profit

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thinking in percentages instead of amounts makes it seem like I didn't give him as good of a deal as I thought. I'll try going near 50% next time and see what happens.

Comment: If your broker has a high enough appraiser skill, you can buy tens of thousands of dwarfbucks' worth of goods while only giving the merchant a profit of several hundred. Usually I sell all of the vendor trash available to make sure the size of caravans that visit my fortress keeps growing, though.

Comment: I tend to churn out stone crafts like nobodies business.  If they're willing to take more of the junk off my hands, they can have it!

Comment: My favorite is mugs. Three stone mugs from a single stone block!

Comment: I would be all for it, but his counter offers were for my much needed bolts. I brought em all to the depot just in case I would need to trade them and he wanted over 500 of em. If this was one of the fortresses where I was constantly attacked, I would be offloading hella goblinite instead haha.